# Enable-Migrations causes project failed to build

Tags: wpf, nuget

I have created a sample WPF project, worked fine.
I added a MVVMLight project, made it a default startup project, and ran fine.

Now I added a class library project, and added an ADO.NET data model with "Code First From Database", and selected relevant tables, that gave me a good collection of entity classes.

I thought this way, I can keep my data model seperate from presentation and businesss logic layers, plus add additional target plateforms if needed and take the advantage of SoC.

So far so good.

### Now I want to enable Migrations on my data layer only. I fired up Nuget console, selected dataLayer project in the "Default Project" drop down. Issued Enable-Migrations command and very first error I got was

### "No connection string named 'dpFinDataModel' could be found in the application config file."

Now I modified Startup project - i.e. Mvvm project's App.Config to add App.Config details from DataLayer project.

### Tried to rerun "Enable-Migrations", and following error occured:

PM> Enable-Migrations

### The project 'dpFinMvvm' failed to build.

Am I doing something wrong here? 
Will this approach work?

Thanks for all your help.
-DP

Answer (score 1):

1) PM> Enable-Migrations would get an error if your project itself contains errors.

Try going through your code such as in debug mode and check if you have any build errors then try.

2) And for your config file error you may have not referenced it properly, try this tutorial to solve your issue.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application